# Using of construction "It to be not until ...that ..."

Tags: grammar

Is this construction used correctly?

> It was not until his becoming the manager that he got married.

Comment: Proofreading without identifying the source of concern is off-topic here. Also, don't use "native" without specific reasoning, along with native where. There is a lot of variation around the world.

Comment: I have just changed my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think technically it is OK to say this, but it would sound better if you wrote: "It was not until he became a manager that he got married."

"Becoming a manager" implies that the process of "becoming" is important (for example, learning what his new duties are).

Comment: Thank you. BTW.  (until) is not preposition here . Is it true ?

Comment: "until" is never a preposition.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, that structure is correct but it could sound better if you say:

```
It was not until he became the manager that he got married.
```

If you say "becoming", you emphasise the process of becoming manager. Despite that I think you should state the sentence like it is a fact using infinitive after  **"It to be not until + subject"**.